# asyncio event_loop declared outside of a class with asyncio.coroutine methods fails with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'"

Tags: python, class

Exploring Python 3.4.0's asyncio module, I am attempting to create a class with asyncio.coroutine methods that are called from an event_loop outside of the class.

My working code is below.

```
import asyncio

class Foo():
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def async_sleep(self):
        print('about to async sleep')
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def call_as(self):
        print('about to call ass')
        yield from self.async_sleep()

    def run_loop(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.call_as())
        print('done with loop')
        loop.close()

a = Foo()
a.run_loop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(a.call_as())
```

The call to `a.run_loop()` provides output as expected:

```
python3 async_class.py
about to call ass
about to async sleep
done with loop
```

However as soon as the event_loop attempts to process `a.call_as()` I get the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "async_class.py", line 26, in <module>
    doop.run_until_complete(asyncio.async(a.call_ass()))
  File "/opt/boxen/homebrew/opt/pyenv/versions/3.4.0/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 203, in run_until_complete
self.run_forever()
  File "/opt/boxen/homebrew/opt/pyenv/versions/3.4.0/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 184, in run_forever
self._run_once()
  File "/opt/boxen/homebrew/opt/pyenv/versions/3.4.0/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 778, in _run_once
event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'
```

I have attempted wrapping `a.call_as()` in an `asyncio.Task()`, `asyncio.async()` and the failure is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was with the context of the event loop.

`asyncio` magically creates an event loop for a thread at runtime.  This event loop's context is set when `.get_event_loop()` is called.

In the above example, `a.run_loop` sets the event loop inside the context of `Foo.run_loop`.

One kicker of event loops is that there may only be one event loop per thread, and a given event loop can only process events in its context.

With that in mind, note that the `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` just after `a.run_loop` is asking to assign the thread's event loop to the `__main__` context.  Unfortunately, the event loop was already set to the context of `Foo.run_loop`, so a `None` type is set for the `__main__` event loop.

Instead, it is necessary to create a new event loop and then set that event loop's context to `__main__`, i.e.

```
new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(new_loop)
```

Only then will an event loop be properly set in the context of `__main__`, allowing for the proper execution of our now-modified `new_loop.run_until_complete(a.call_as())`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you close the eventloop at the end of Foo.run_loop()

From [BaseEventLoop.close](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.close)

> Close the event loop. The loop must not be running. Pending callbacks will be lost.
>
> This clears the queues and shuts down the executor, but does not wait for the executor to finish.
>
> This is idempotent and irreversible. No other methods should be called after this one.